# Locating html code in local joomla server files

Tags: html, css, joomla

I have been tinkering with joomla recently.I was able to change css style using chrome dev tool, which helped me locate the css code that is responsible for the style I inspect. Now I want the same for html codes. The template that I'm using has an offcanvas menu, and when I inspect it, I can see the codes that form the menu, and I want to modify them, as I did with many css codes, however there is no locate or open containing file for html elements. Is there a way to do this? Since I did not write this template, I don't know which is which and where. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Joomla layout overrides to achieve what you describe, check out this link for full details:
https://docs.joomla.org/Understanding_Output_Overrides#Module_Layout_Overrides

The idea is that you move a copy of the module file you want to modify to
**/templates/your_template/html/** and Joomla will override the original output with the output from your custom file. You can do the same with components and plugins, it's really powerful.

Another reason that overrides are the way to go is that there's no risk that you'll loose your changes when you update the extension you are customising.

If you Google Joomla overrides you'll find other resources and once you get started you'll find it's surprisingly easy :)

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend editing css or html in Joomla via the dev tools, because of the problem you're having - sometimes it's hard to know what(and where) exactly you're changing something.

If you have access to the file for the template it should have a pretty straightforward file structure, i.e. all the html is in a html folder, the css in  a css folder etc. Learn more [here](https://docs.joomla.org/Understanding_Joomla!_templates).

I recommend locating those files and editing them with a text editor.

Comment: html file has like 20 sub files and each of those sub files have sub files to. things that I'm changing are basic stuff and I know what I'm doing, I only need to locate this specific code in my folders

Answer (score 0):

To make a file depends on the framework you add one to Joomla template is not used.
But in all cases you index.php is a file that can address the heads of a css  your new address